# Alternative to Image Picker Image Picker crashes on some devices

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I have been having issues with image picker, my apps keeps crashing on some device, after 2 to 3 snaps even with the latest update, I have tried many things but the problem still persists, it seems I am not the only as the issues as been raised but yet it hasn't been resolved. I have been on it for 2 days.

```
                         Row( crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                            child: Padding(
                                          padding:
                                              const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                  0, 19, 0, 0),
                                          child: Text(
                                              'Vehicle Exterior Front'),
                                        )),
                                        ElevatedButton(
                                          onPressed: () async {
                                            final pickedImage =
                                                await ImagePicker()
                                                    .getImage(
                                                        source: ImageSource
                                                            .camera);
                                            _image = pickedImage != null
                                                ? File(pickedImage.path)
                                                : null;
                                            if (_image != null) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                _image =
                                                    File(pickedImage!.path);
                                              });
                                            }
                                          },
                                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                            minimumSize: Size(100, 29),
                                            fixedSize: Size(10.0, 9.0),
                                            primary: Color(0xff1565D8),
                                            shape:
                                                new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  new BorderRadius.circular(
                                                      5.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                "upload",
                                                style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.w700,
                                                    fontSize: 10,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                                  'assets/svg/camera.svg',
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Multi Image Picker for this as same process for this :

```
 multi_image_picker: 4.7.15
```

I'm Using below Code to select multiple images by using file_picker: ^2.0.7 Library. Long press to select multiple image. Once Image Selected you can use f arr to display the images.

```
    List<File> f = List();

     RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Pick Image"),
        onPressed: () async {
          FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
            allowMultiple: true,
            type: FileType.custom,
            allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'],
          );
          if (result != null) {
            f = result.paths.map((path) => File(path)).toList();
            setState(() {});
            print(f);
          }
        },
      ),
```

Its just idea you can use in your code :-)

Comment: Any other suggested alternative image pickers which can use for selecting multiple images in the same view?